# SSRS: Jump to report drillthrough link with relative and absolute paths outside of Reports folder

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, hyperlink, rdl, drillthrough

I have two reps, constructed in VS 2005 and running in sharepoint mode (Sharepoint 2005, IE11, SQL Server 2008R2). Their locations (whatever):

- https://bi.bcs.ru:4433/**reports/DocLib**/Clients.rdl
- https://bi.bcs.ru:4433/**ssp/DocLib7**/Client_mooves.rdl

Now, I want to make a drillthrough link from Clients.rdl to Client_mooves.rdl. I try to build a valid link for "Jump to report" field. Here is my tryes and fails:

- **(a) use relative link** "../../ssp/DocLib7/Client_mooves.rdl". **Error**: Cannot find element
  "https://bi.bcs.ru:4433/**reports**/ssp/DocLib7/Client_mooves.rdl".
  (rsItemNotFound). **Comment**: somehow SSRS addes "/reports/" folder
  to the root path, don't know why.
- **(b) use absolute link** "/ssp/DocLib7/Client_mooves.rdl". **Error**: An error occurred during report rendering.
- **(c) use full url link** "https%3a//bi.bcs.ru%3a4433/ssp/DocLib7/Client_mooves.rdl".
  **Error**: Cannot find element "https://bi.bcs.ru:4433/**reports**/ssp/DocLib7/Client_mooves.rdl".
  (rsItemNotFound) . **Comment**: it's the same err as in (a) with
  "/reports/" folder, added to the root.

How can I force my link in 'Jump to report' field to open reports in **"[root]/ssp/**" folder, i.e. out of **"[root]/reports/**" folder? Note: I can not moove reports between folders and unable to use 'Jump to url' links (they does not work at our portal, may be, it's becase of sharepoint mode, url links are ignored somehow and are not clickable)

Comment: looks like "/reports/" folder is considered as part of the root path. In MSDN I found some information about TargetReportFolder property, which stores url of the Sharepoint library for reports. But I cannot check it, because I do not have access to administrative part of our sharepoint portal

Answer (score 0):

found a workaround. "Jump to url" links do really work, but there are constraints regarding url's http/https protocol.

For http protocol valid syntax is:

- http://ya.ru
- ="http://ya.ru"
- ="javascript:void window.open('http://ya.ru', '_blank');"

For https protocol the only operable syntax is:

- ="javascript:void window.open('https://bi.bcs.ru:4433/', '_blank');"

while these two do not work:

- https://bi.bcs.ru:4433/
- ="https://bi.bcs.ru:4433/"

Still, if anybody knowes how to force "Jump to report" run - you are welcome and strongly appreciated, folks!

Comment: The bad news is that in Sharepoint integrated mode SSRS 2005 does not support parameter passing through urls, that's nuts! So I need a "Jump to report" solution to pass params. !!! Folks, help !!!